# Embedded Wordpress Feature - What do I Need?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to create a feature that would allow Wordpress users to be able to insert this into their blog posts:

- Car Title (heading)
- Car Description (paragraph)
- Photograph of car (image)
- List of items (bullet list)
- Steps for how to assemble car parts (e.g. a gearbox) (heading, paragraph, heading, paragraph...)

It should be really easy for users to insert into their blog post.

Is this possible? If so, what would I need to develop for this - a plugin, widget, other?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TDO Mini Forms](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tdo-mini-forms/) plugin.

Comment: +1, although I actually want to include some other functionality, such as optionally allow users to centralise all of the data into 1 site. But at least the TDO Mini Forms plugin shows that I can achieve what I want via a plugin - i.e. make it easy for users to embed the content into their blog.